Should I bother trying to teach my niece I won't respond to tantrums if I only see her once a month and risk her mom undermining me if I don't give in
I get to see my niece roughly once a month.  Her mother, who is raising her, is not related to me, but we get along well enough.  Unfortunately the mother allows her daughter to get away with throwing tantrums to get what she wants.  My niece is generally a good kid usually and often cooperates with me, it's kind of random when she will happily go along with something and when a tantrum will happen.
Now I have plenty of experience with different kids, and have dealt with tantrums before. I know how to handle tantrums and express to a child that I love them - even when they are throwing tantrums - but that I also won't give in to a tantrums when I'm officially in charge, I have plenty of practice with that.  My problem is that the mother is usually near by during my visits and will show up when she hears her daughter crying.  After that the daughter usually ends up getting what she wanted from Mom, meaning her tantrum still ended up working!
To give an idea of frequency I spent half a day with her on Sunday and had to deal with two tantrums in that time.   In both cases I refused to give in, in one case Mom came to comfort my niece in the middle of the tantrum rewarding her fighting with extra attention.  The other time I just barely managed to get her to say sorry - I'd refused to continue our game until she apologized to her cousin which triggered the tantrum - but only by partially playing dumb with mom as to the cause of the tantrum, distracting Mom for a minute, and dumb luck that niece was just at the state where she was ready to reengage and thankfully didn't decide to keep fighting saying sorry when I asked for it a second time.  I felt like I was walking a tightrope trying to get a simple sorry out of my niece now that mom was around.
I know kids can understand different adults have different rules, but if mom is usually close enough to come in and reward the tantrum when I refuse to I'm not sure my niece will learn she shouldn't try tantrums with me; after all tantrums still work via summoning mom. Can a 4 year old really be expected to learn and remember that I won't support tantrums if she sees me only once a month and my attempt to teach her are often interrupted by mom?
I know how to handle tantrums with kids I only volunteer with and won't see regularly as well, I could better distract and defuse such a situation if I wasn't actively trying to teach my niece that she shouldn't try to use tantrums to get things out of me.  So I'm torn between using tantrums as a teaching moment to show her  that they won't work - which is what I'd prefer to do if it wasn't for my concern it won't work if mom is around- and giving up on teaching and simply resorting to defusing the situation as easily as I can (without fully giving in to the tantrum, I simple refuse to do that), so I can get back to having fun with her and making the most of my visits.
Before anyone suggests it, mom is not open to parenting advice from me.  Talking with her about my concerns won't fix things, and could potentially risk alienating her and making it harder to get visits with my niece so it's not really something I want to risk.

"Can a 4 year old really be expected to learn and remember that I won't support tantrums if she sees me only once a month and my attempt to teach her are often interrupted by mom?" If this is your question (and I think it is), then please be more direct so people don't answer a different question (e.g. What should I do?) Thanks.

"My problem is that the mother is usually near by during my visits": is she ever not?  Is the child's behavior different depending on whether she knows the mother is within hearing distance?  If so then the child already knows that her tantrums are ineffective with you.

How about soliciting advice from the mom?

I've noticed that she gets very upset when she's asked to do something she doesn't want to do, such as [specific actual example].  Do you have any suggestions for things that often work to help her manage the situation while still accomplishing the needed goal?

I would avoid using the word 'tantrum', as it's both a somewhat loaded word but also a relatively poorly descriptive word (as it doesn't describe exactly what's happening, why it's happening, or really help explain how to solve it).  Children cry for many reasons when things aren't going exactly their way, and it's not always "to get their way" - though it might seem that way sometimes.
Either way, each child is different, and mom might have some suggestions for things that work well with your neice, as she obviously navigates this on a regular basis.

Love the qualification of "tantrum". If people understood the root cause of tantrums and reframed it as something other than a power struggle which must be "won", responses might be much better. So, +1. However, mom might not know how to navigate this either.


Can a 4 year old really be expected to learn and remember that I won't support tantrums if she sees me only once a month and my attempt to teach her are often interrupted by mom?

I'm going to address this by assuming that by "tantrums" you mean "crying when you don't give into unreasonable demands." At 4, she may recognize you are not giving into the tantrums, but as you admit, she doesn't throw tantrums as a tool to manipulate you to give her what she wants. If anything, she is using it as a tool to summon her mom. Most likely, however, she is just expressing her feelings.
She's only 4, and she's still learning how to navigate her feelings when she doesn't get what she wants. If you give into her unreasonable demands, she will most likely recognize the pattern and continue the behavior when she is with you. If you don't give into her unreasonable demands, she may recognize she still gets what she wants from her mom, but as she gets older, she will start to recognize it comes from her mom and not from you. If you try to change how you respond to that behavior as she gets older, it could strain your relationship with her. The best thing you can do for her is to stay consistent. As you do this, she will grow to respect you and feel safe around you because she knows what to expect from you when you're together, whether her mom is around or not.
My advice is to do what you typically do when most kids cry about not getting their way. Make sure basic needs are met, acknowledge their feelings, help them know that they are loved, and help them work through it without giving in. If mom shows up and gives them what they want, then there's nothing you can do about it, but at least you stayed consistent.
Reading between the lines, I sense some tension and/or resentment between you and the mom about the situation. I suggest sitting down with mom and just telling her what you plan to do when her daughter is crying about something unreasonable. I would tell her that she's more than welcome to step in if she wants to, but that when you're in charge, this is how you're going to handle it. If mom doesn't like your suggestion, then you two can work something out together that you're both happy with. Here's a template to start your conversation if you'd like.

Hey <insert mom's name>, I've been feeling unsure about how to respond when <insert niece's name> cries about not getting something that she wants. I want to get your thoughts on the best thing to do, and since you're her mom, you know how to help her best. This is my plan, and what I usually do (tell her what you do). Do you have any suggestions?

Then take it from there. Make sure it's about you asking for her advice, and not about telling the mom she's doing something wrong, or giving her unsolicited advice. Do your best to encourage the mom and praise her for things you genuinely think she does well as a mom. The mom will most likely appreciate your concern and your willingness to ask for help. Hopefully the discussion will help her feel more comfortable with you so you don't risk losing your visits with your niece.
